# SignalR not hitting OnConnected and giving Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I am trying to setup SignalR at my ASP.NET MVC site and a Javascript client.

This is my client:

```
@section scripts{
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var connection = $.connection('/MY_ENDPOINT');

        connection.received(function (data) {
            $('#chatArea').append('>>' + data + "\r\n");
        });


        connection.start().done(function () {
            $("#send").click(function () {
                connection.send($('#msg').val());
                $("#msg").val("");
            });
        });

        connection.error(function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        });

    });
</script>
}
```

Of course, I have the corresponding HTML elements `chatArea` and `msg`. In server, here is what I did:

- Installed SignalR (latest version currently, 2.0.2) through NuGet.
- Added `app.MapSignalR("MY_ENDPOINT", new Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.HubConfiguration());` in startup configuration, made sure it is called before registering auth methods.
- I've subclassed `PersistentConnection` and overridden `OnConnected` and `OnReceived` methods.

However, when I run my app and navigate to the page, I can see that my endpoint's `negotiate` and `connect` methods are called, they both return OK (HTTP 200). I try to send anything using the webpage by clicking the "send" button, and at the server side I'm getting this error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException'
occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Additional information: Unexpected character encountered while 
parsing value: a. Path '', line 0, position 0.
```

What could be the cause of this error?

**UPDATE:** I also have an iOS app with the SignalR-ObjC framework, and I can connect. However, when I try to send any data over it, I'm getting:

`2014-03-06 19:39:39.853 Tanisalim[54987:70b] Websocket error: Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Request failed: internal server error (500)" UserInfo=0xade84e0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://10.211.55.3/api/socket/send?transport=longPolling&connectionData=(null)&connectionToken=xybYQ8ItTN0IWUbyrosuHy%2F3jN0krIyHLO6b6Gq8VdC3orwRRGkVSIgtYkNQINVLhRMW77cX%2BU2LiHxoe0eDE3ZumT7JrObJcQ%2FXyHiP25%2BQy%2BZizHEHbsPyBBomERoI, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: internal server error (500), NSUnderlyingError=0xade1290 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html"`

Still, no server-side breakpoints are hit.

Comment: What is the value of #msg it is not parsing successfully on server side.

Comment: Use http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your JSON

Comment: It is just some sample, short text such as `sadfasd`.